# What is the correct way to add a custom module to the AutoPyTorch pipeline?

Tags: python, pytorch, automl

I need to add a custom module to my search space when using the [Auto-PyTorch](https://github.com/automl/Auto-PyTorch) library. Specifically, I would like to add a custom backbone while using TabularClassificationPipeline.

It is pretty clear to me which methods and attributes my custom module should have, but I don't understand how to pass it to the pipeline itself.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

*I tried reading their official docs, however, there is no such example there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.